# How do I make two updates using one SQLite query in a Windows Forms application?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, sqlite

I'm trying to update two columns in one query. Basically, I am transferring an amount from one account to another, so I need to update the balance of both columns.

```
using (SQLiteCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
{
    try
    {
        // Adds customers details to the database
        cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE account SET balance = balance + (CASE WHEN accid = @in THEN 1000 else - 1000 END)WHERE accid IN(@in, @out)";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("in", cb_accidIn.SelectedItem);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("out", cb_accidOut.SelectedItem);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

That is what I have at the moment, but I get a "database is locked error".

```
UPDATE account SET balance = balance + (CASE WHEN accid = 1 THEN 1000 else - 1000 END)
WHERE accid IN (1, 2)
```

That's the SQLite query I tried in database browser and that works fine in there.

Comment: Your sql code is syntactically correct. Make sure that the db is not used by any other app, like db browser. Or that you have closed any other connections.

Comment: hey thanks so much closed db browser now it worlks, cant believe thats all it was haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change your parameters:

```
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@in", (int)  cb_accidIn.SelectedValue);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@out", (int) cb_accidOut.SelectedValue);
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the gist?